# Inconsistent behaviour with multi-stage build sharing volume between Docker Compose services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-multi-stage-build

Very inconsistent behaviour sharing the same volume and populating the folder in a Compose multi-stage build. Not all files are visible, only files from one container or another (depends on the run).

- Shared volume is `public`
- Container `caddy` mounts `public` at `/srv/public/`
- Container `php` mounts `public` at `/var/www/html/public/`

During the build, both write something in their `public` folder. The resulting volume only show files from the `caddy` stage or `php` stage, but not both.

In this run, `public/build/` is missing:

```
$ docker compose exec caddy ls -la public
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 18 17:47 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 18 17:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 18 17:47 bundles
```

Same output for `php` service:

```
$ docker compose exec php ls -la public
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 18 17:47 .
drwxrwxrwt    1 www-data www-data      4096 May 18 17:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 18 17:47 bundles
```

The docker file:

```
# [STAGE] php-prod
FROM php:fpm-alpine AS php
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Create public/bundles/foo/bar.js
RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p public/bundles/foo; \
    touch public/bundles/foo/bar.js

# [STAGE] caddy
FROM caddy:latest as caddy
WORKDIR /srv

# Create public/build/baz.js
RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p public/build; \
    touch public/build/baz.js
```

And the Compose file:

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  caddy:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: caddy
    volumes:
      - public:/srv/public/

  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: php
    volumes:
      - public:/var/www/html/public/

volumes:
  public:
```

Can you explain the incosistent behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use volumes to merge content from two different sources this way.  There are a number of practical problems with using volumes to try to publish files out of one image to another container, and I'd avoid it entirely.

The best approach here will be to `COPY` the files into the proxy image.  With the setup you've shown, this is particularly straightforward since you're already building a custom image out of the same source tree.

```bash
FROM php:fpm-alpine AS php
...

FROM caddy:latest as caddy
WORKDIR /srv

# Create public/build/baz.js
RUN mkdir -p public/build && \
    touch public/build/baz.js

# Copy the files out of the PHP application image
COPY --from=php /var/www/html/public/bundles/ ./public/bundles/
```

Then when you run this, delete all of the `volumes:` blocks from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

---

When you build an image, it does not create or populate volumes; the setup you have does not use the Dockerfile `COPY` lines to populate named volumes.  (Try running `docker-compose down -v`, `docker-compose build`, and then `docker volume ls`; you will not have any volumes at this point.)

The actual rules around named volumes are that, if

1. The volume is a named or anonymous Docker volume, but not a bind mount or a mount in another container system like Kubernetes; and
2. The volume is totally empty

then, and only then, content is copied from the image at the mount point into the volume.  Whatever's in the volume then hides what was in the image.

This is consistent with the behavior you describe in the question.  Whichever of the two containers starts first, its content gets copied into the volume; then when the second container is started, the volume isn't empty so nothing gets copied, but the volume content copied from the first image hides the second image's content.

Other cases that won't work here: if you change the static files and rebuild the image, the volume won't get updated, so you won't see the change; if you use a bind mount instead of a named volume, you'll just get the empty directory from the host; if you go to deploy this on Kubernetes with a PersistentVolumeClaim, the volume will also remain empty.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such an explanation. In my example i used RUN but in my real example I'm using COPY, but I guess it's the same. If both image A and B use COPY into public folder, the incosistent behaviour seems the same. Can you confirm it?

Comment: Yes, `RUN` and `COPY` will work the same way here.  In both cases the files are in one or the other of the image, and the volume isn't created or populated until you run a container.

Comment: Any link to investigate furter? For me, even the bind mount doesn't work either, it's frustrating. I.e. `php` service mounts /public/.:/var/www/html/public. During the build, `php` copy some assets into /var/www/html/public/build.... when I start the containers, `php` won't even show /var/www/html/public/build....

Comment: Delete all of the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file.  All of the required files should be `COPY`ed into their images.

Comment: _If you bind-mount a directory into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount._ (from the docs) so bind-mount is not an option since files should be visible to the containers. The additional difficulty is that both caddy and php should access the same folder (volume)... that's the original question. I'm still elaborate yuor answer!

Comment: Note that this is true of all kinds of mounts in any Unix environment; it's true of named volumes, and without Docker it'd also be true if you did something like mount a USB drive over your application's source tree (the contents of the USB disk would hide your application and nothing would get copied).  I don't think volumes should be part of this solution at all.

Comment: I've asked another question because i think that you answered this already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76289653 if you want to take a look. Thanks!